# How do you add indexes to your Mongoid database in Padrino?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, padrino

I need to be able to add indexes to my Mongoid database in a Padrino project.  I saw that they added rake tasks for this here:

https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/commit/ec8a267f477ac4dc88a66c84fffb17ac26190a22

And it seems that they should be accessed by doing this, but I get an error:

```
$ padrino-gen orm::mongoid --help
=> Problem loading ./config/boot.rb
=> Invalid option :index provided to relation :features. Valid options are: as, autosave, dependent, foreign_key, order, class_name, extend, inverse_class_name, inverse_of, name, relation, validate.
  /Users/jeremysmith/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mongoid-2.2.1/lib/mongoid/relations/options.rb:41:in `block in validate!'
```

Any idea of how to run a rake task to add indexes in Padrino?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you generated your Padrino project, did you select mongoid as the persistence engine? Hint: easy to check by looking at the `.components` file in your project root. If you did, you should be able to access the rake tasks just using `padrino rake <namespace>:<task>`. See here: http://www.padrinorb.com/guides/rake-tasks#orm .

Running a rake task to create an index should be just: `padrino rake mongoid:create_indexes`

I would check `padrino rake -T` to see the list of available tasks as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
bundle exec padrino rake mi:create_indexes
```

(not mongoid:create_indexes as you will see elsewhere online)

This seems to be the new name for this rake task in Padrino 0.10.5 and Mongoid 2.3.4